# Using AsyncTask in onFocusChange using JAVA in Android

Tags: java, android

Im using `AsyncTask` in `onFocusChangeListener` for `EditText`. So if value changes it goes to `api` call.

What if user changes `edittext` value often and out of focus to see the value in `textview`.

How to manage it to avoid multiple instances?

As i need to get the result instantly to display it in `textview` according to the changes of `EditText` value. 
Thanks!

```
@Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
        if(!b){
            Api api = new Api(MyActivity.this);
            api.setHttpType(Api.HTTP_TYPE.GET);
            api.setParams(null, "www.url.com");
            api.responseCallBack(new Api.ResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void jsonResponse(String result) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result.trim());
                        textView.setText(jsonObject.getString("response"));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }


                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Api api = new Api(MyActivity.this);
            api.setHttpType(Api.HTTP_TYPE.GET);
            api.setParams(null, "www.url.com");

Use these values globally

Comment: Im already using 2 more api calls in same activity for different url!

Comment: then set URL in every call

Answer (score 0):

You can add a TextWatcher using *EditText.addTextChangedListener()* to get the changed, however using AsyncTask you cannot avoid multiple instance.

The only solution is to create an Thread and send requests to it when the "TextWatcher.onTextChanged(..)" is raised. In that new Thread you can do synchronous HTTP calls without bothering about latency/blocking_thread.

```
TextWatcher.onTextChanged(CharSequence s, ...) {
    if (mNewThreadHandler !) null) {
        mNewThreadHandler.removeMessages(1);  //remove all previously queued Message of same "1" type
          //send/enqueue the newer "1" Message type
        mNewThreadHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(mNewThreadHandler, 1, s));
    }
}
```

The HandlerThread:

```
Handler mNewThreadHandler = null;
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        mNewThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.myLooper) {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(@NonNull final Message message) {
                switch (message.what) {
                    case: 1: {
                        Log.e(TAG, "__TEXT_CHANGED__");
                        ...do Http request here...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```